# How to inject a value from HttpSession instead of the session

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, httpsession

When using spring MVC it's really easy to pass the HttpSession to a method by just adding `HttpSession session` to the signature of the method, and later you can do something like

```
Integer valueFromSession = (Integer) session.getAttribute("key1")
Integer anotherValueFromSession = (Integer) session.getAttribute("key2")
```

The problem that I'm having right now is that we need values from the session in a lot of different methods in a lot of different controllers, so my question is if it's possible to get the value from the session and automatically inject it to the method and therefore instead of:

```
@GetMapping("/something")
public String foo(HttpSession session) {
    Integer valueFromSession = (Integer) session.getAttribute("key1")
    Integer anotherValueFromSession = (Integer) session.getAttribute("key2")

    return someMethod(valueFromSession, anotherValueFromSession);
}
```

I can have:

```
@GetMapping("/something")
public String foo(HttpSessionData dataFromSession) {

    return someMethod(dataFromSession.getValue(), dataFromSession.getAnotherValue();
}
```

Where DataFromSession is a class that gets populated from the HttpSession. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `@SessionAttribute` with spring MVC, it will retrieve the existing attribute from session, more see [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.12.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-sessionattrib-global)

```
@GetMapping("/something")
public String foo(@SessionAttribute("key1") Integer key1, @SessionAttribute("key2") Integer key2) {
    return someMethod(key1, key2);
}
```